# Ошибка линковки с cpprest

Tags: c++, linux, qt, rest

Доброго времени суток!
Пишем с товарищем в QT проект на C++ (под Ubuntu). Используем в том числе библиотеку cpprest. Сначала все шло хорошо. Однако после того, как я переустановил ОС проект перестал собираться. Скриншот вывода компилятора прикладываю. У товарища код компилируется.

```
client.o: In function `Client::AddFriend(QString)':
client.cpp:(.text+0x112c): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x11a9): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1200): undefined reference to `web::json::value::value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1235): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x12b4): undefined reference to `web::uri::uri(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x13c7): undefined reference to `web::http::methods::POST[abi:cxx11]'
client.o: In function `Client::accountRequest(accountRequest, QString)':
client.cpp:(.text+0x17bf): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1816): undefined reference to `web::json::value::value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x184b): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x18b8): undefined reference to `web::json::value::value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x18ed): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1962): undefined reference to `web::json::value::value(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1997): undefined reference to `web::json::value::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1bbc): undefined reference to `web::uri::uri(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x1c53): undefined reference to `web::http::methods::POST[abi:cxx11]'
client.o: In function `std::_Function_handler<void (pplx::task<web::http::http_response="">), Client::AddFriend(QString)::{lambda(pplx::task<web::http::http_response>)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, pplx::task<web::http::http_response>&&)':
client.cpp:(.text+0x2537): undefined reference to `web::json::value::at(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.cpp:(.text+0x253f): undefined reference to `web::json::value::as_string[abi:cxx11]() const'
client.cpp:(.text+0x25df): undefined reference to `web::json::value::at(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.o: In function `web::http::http_request::set_body(web::json::value const&)':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE[_ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE]+0x3d): undefined reference to `web::json::value::serialize[abi:cxx11]() const'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE[_ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE]+0x48): undefined reference to `utility::conversions::to_utf8string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE[_ZN3web4http12http_request8set_bodyERKNS_4json5valueE]+0x4a1): undefined reference to `web::http::details::http_msg_base::set_body(Concurrency::streams::basic_istream<unsigned char=""> const&, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
client.o: In function `web::http::client::http_client::request(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&, web::json::value const&, pplx::cancellation_token const&)':
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3web4http6client11http_client7requestERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_RKNS_4json5valueERKN4pplx18cancellation_tokenE[_ZN3web4http6client11http_client7requestERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_RKNS_4json5valueERKN4pplx18cancellation_tokenE]+0xf1): undefined reference to `web::http::details::_http_request::_http_request(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> >)'
client.cpp:(.text._ZN3web4http6client11http_client7requestERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_RKNS_4json5valueERKN4pplx18cancellation_tokenE[_ZN3web4http6client11http_client7requestERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_RKNS_4json5valueERKN4pplx18cancellation_tokenE]+0x184): undefined reference to `web::uri::uri(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char="">, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

В .pro путь к cpprest указан, пересобирать пробовал, переустанавливать систему пробовал, не помогает.

UPD
часть кода, для которого в том числе выскакивает ошибка

```
json::value json;
json["request"]      = json::value( U("account") );
json["sub_request"]  = json::value( U(property.toStdString()) );
json["login"]        = json::value( U(req.login.toStdString()) );
json["key"]          = json::value( U(req.password.toStdString()) );
```

Comment: У товарища компилируется?

Comment: создайте, пожалуйста, [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Cerbo да, у товарища компилируется

Comment: @alexanderbarakin впервые пишу сюда, не очень понял, что конкретно в моем посте не так? можете уточнить?

Comment: @Alexey, перейдите, пожалуйста, по ссылке, которую я привёл.

Comment: @Alexey Скорее всего у вас cpprest неправильно собран или беда с путями поиска. Пути можно в консоли при сборке увидеть, возможно придется "подробность" вывода поднять.